# Insert a "sql query" to a sql table

Tags: python, sql

I am making a logs of an automated scripts by adding all 'insert' events to a separate table called 'sqlcommand' table. I have two separate tables, btureading table, and sqlcommand table. btureading will logs all output from a number, and sqlcommand will log the insert command.

However, I'm encountering an error on the SQL syntax

```
import mysql.connector as sql
import random as rd
from datetime import datetime
def conndev():
    conn_dev = sql.connect(
        host = 'localhost',
        user = 'root',
        passwd = '',
        auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
        db = 'test_db'
        )
    return conn_dev

def insertsqlcommand(sql_insert):
    mydb = conndev()
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    insert_sql_table = "INSERT INTO sqlcommand(sqlStatement) value('" + sql_insert + "')"
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(insert_sql_table)
    mydb.commit()

def insertTodbMeter(myVal):
    mydb = conndev()
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql_insert = "INSERT INTO btureading(sensorId,dt,flowRate,velocity,netTotalizer)VALUES('"+myVal+"')"
    mycursor= mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(sql_insert)
    mydb.commit()
    return sql_insert

ts = str(datetime.now())[0:19]
flowRate= str(rd.random())  
velocity= str(rd.random())
netTotalizer= str(rd.random())


for i in range(20):
    sample_data = str(i+1)+",'"+ts+"',"+flowRate+","+velocity+","+netTotalizer+","+posTotalizer+","+negTotalizer
    x = insertTodbMeter(sample)
    insertsqlcommand(x)
```

Comment: Just replace `value` with `values` in `"INSERT INTO sqlcommand(sqlStatement) value...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're encountering an error, please provide the error (full stack trace whenever possible). Even without that, though, you either are having or will have trouble with incorrectly handled insertions.

`sample_data = str(i+1)+`**`",'"+ts+"',"`**`+flowRate+","+velocity+","+netTotalizer+","+posTotalizer+","+negTotalizer`

The bolding here shows where you are adding single quotes to `sample_data`. Then you're calling `insertTodbMeter` with a value that contains single quotes, but the values are not all quoted, which means this will break:

`sql_insert = "INSERT INTO btureading(sensorId,dt,flowRate,velocity,netTotalizer)VALUES(`**`'"+myVal+"'`**`)"`

The right way to do this is with prepared statements/parameterized queries. Don't attempt to build a SQL string; pass your values in and let the database library handle that. Here's a starting point based on [this example](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/#What_is_parameterized_query_in_python):

```
def insert_to_db_meter(sensor_id, dt, flow_rate, velocity, net_totalizer):
    mydb = conndev()
    mycursor= mydb.cursor(prepared=True)

    sql_insert = """
        INSERT INTO btureading (
            sensorId,
            dt,
            flowRate,
            velocity,
            netTotalizer
        )
        VALUES (
            %s,
            %s,
            %s,
            %s,
            %s
        )
    """
    mycursor.execute(
        sql_insert, 
        (
            sensor_id, 
            dt, 
            flow_rate, 
            velocity, 
            net_totalizer,
        ),
    )
    mydb.commit()

    return sql_insert
```

Answer (score 0):

**Insert a sql query to a sql table**

**Reference the document**

https://pynative.com/python-mysql-insert-data-into-database-table/